# Xcode does not see my developer certificate in Code Signing Identity

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain, codesign

I renewed my IOS Developer Certificate, i deleted old ones from keychains and clicked on my certificate. Everything looks normal in keychains, i have distribution,developer, WWDC certificates in there.Every profile look valid with green marks Under Teams and Provisioning Profiles section in Organizer but in Xcode under Code Signing Identity there is no profile currently match developer profile under Automatic Profile Selector(Recommended). What can i do about it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you changed the project identifier?? or your certificate may have different package identifier. check that first.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger Project's bundle Identifier is same with profile's. I also created new project and there is also no any recommended profile so i cant use any device with Xcode, I just can run the project on simulations.

Comment: Have you refreshed the provisioning profiles in organizer??

Comment: @ArmaanStranger When i click refresh button, it waits and then i m getting "The request timed out" error.

Comment: The issue might be that Apple's Distribution portal is not working right now so that it might not connect to server that's why you are seeing this. I think you should wait until Apple completes his Maintenance.

Comment: Is there a way around this? Can we download something from the open parts of the dev site so we can work with our projects? I just changed my bundle ID, am ready to distribute adhoc to my tester, but I can't for the above reason.

Comment: @PaulCezanne Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section is open in site, so you can try but my refresh button in organizer still doesn't work.

Comment: @yucelbayram, exactly. Refresh doesn't work but what's the workaround? I've made new new provisioning and dev profiles. Not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: @PaulCezanne Actually i don't know what to do at this moment maybe waiting is best option but if you can run your project on device, probably you can send it to App Store or what excatly do you want to do?

Comment: Right now I can only run on the simulator because of the error. I just got the error Saturday, I'll try to find a workaround today.

Comment: @PaulCezanne and I can't run any new project on my devices, before i could be able to use devices  in every projects without create profiles but only for test. It really bothers me to create Provisioning profile for every project which i want to run on device.thats why happend? do you have an idea?

Comment: nope, sorry, can't help

Comment: I closed the xcode. Then went into the project folder clicked the `.xcodeproj` file and now everything refreshed. If I click the application from the list in the lauch screen nothing changes. Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all check in Xcode -> Preferences -> Account that you have your new profile
 in the list, refresh the list if it needed.

Check in Building Settings of the project that you chose your new profile's certificate as Code Signing Identity for build type that you do (release or debug).

Comment: Very nice solution. I replaced my MacBook and moved my code to New one. This has helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also check that in Xcode -> Preferences -> Account your don`t have red exclamation marks with label "Request timed out"
I had this error, and it is gone after i re-logged in using button near this mark (with entering password, etc)